# Pass variables to other functions in C

Tags: c, redis

I have the following code in `C`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ...

    redisContext *c;
    redisReply *reply;

    ...

    outer_function(...)

    return 0;

}
```

I would like to use the `Redis` variables in the `outer_function`.

I've tried to add a `struct` for this before `main(...)`:

```
typedef struct {
    redisReply reply;
    redisContext c;
} redisStuff;
```

And in `main`:

```
redisContext *c;
redisReply *reply;

redisStuff rs = { reply, c };

...

outer_function((u_char*)&rs, ...)
```

And finally in my `outer_function`:

```
void outer_function(u_char *args, ...) {
    redisStuff *rs = (redisStuff *) args;
    reply = redisCommand(c, "MY-REDIS-COMMAND");
    ...    
    return;
}
```

But it fails with:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'redisReply *' (aka 'struct redisReply *')
```

Comment: `args[0].reply = redisCommand(args[0].c, "MY-REDIS-COMMAND");` here `redisCommand` returns a `redisReply`, but you're assigning it to a `u_char`.

Comment: The error refers to `redisStuff rs = { reply, c };`, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Your struct expects values and you are passing a pointer, so the compiler can't assign a pointer as a `redisContext`.

```
typedef struct {
    redisReply reply;  // <- expects value
    redisContext c;    // <- expects value
} redisStuff;

...

redisContext *c;
redisReply *reply;

redisStuff rs = { reply, c };  // <- reply and c are pointers
```

Comment: Ah, ok. How can I easily change this?

Comment: Either you store the variables as pointers in the struct or you de-reference the pointer when you pass the value >>

typedef struct {
    redisReply *reply;
    redisContext *c;
} redisStuff;

or

redisStuff rs = {*reply, *c}

Comment: Now I reach `outer_function` where I get `error: use of undeclared identifier reply` and `error: use of undeclared identifier c`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void outer_function(redisContext  *c, redisReply **reply) {
    *reply = redisCommand(c, "MY-REDIS-COMMAND");
    ...    
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    redisContext *c;
    redisReply *reply;
    ...
    outer_function(c,&replay);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: other than a spelling 'oops' between `reply` and `replay` this is a good answer